# dealing with blank/missing data with write.table in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame where some of the rows have blanks entries, e.g. to use a toy example

```
Sample Gene RS Chromosome
1      A    rs1 10
2      B        X
3      C    rs4 Y
```

i.e. sample 2 has no rs#. If I attempt to save this data frame in a file using:

```
write.table(mydata,file="myfile",quote=FALSE,sep='\t')
```

and then `read.table('myfile',header=TRUE,sep='\t')`, I get an error stating that the number of entries in line 2 doesn't have 4 elements. If I set `quote=TRUE`, then a `""` entry appears in the table. I'm trying to figure out a way to create a table using `write.table` with `quote=FALSE` while retaining a blank placeholder for rows with missing entries such as 2.

Is there a simple way to do this? I attempted to use the argument `NA=""` in `write.table()` but this didn't change anything.

Comment: Using explicit `NA`s just seems kinder to your end user. Otherwise, maybe try `readr::write_delim`.

Comment: There are no na's in the data frame, just blank spaces (see my example above). What is the simplest way of replacing these blank placeholders with NA?

Comment: `ifelse(df$RS == '', NA, df$RS)` or `dplyr::na_if` are simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If result of my script's data frame has NA I always replace it , One way would be to replace NA in the data frames with a some other text  which tells you that this entry was `NA` in the data frame -Specially if you are saving the result in a csv /database or some non -R env

a simple script to do that

```
replace_NA <- function(x,replacement="N/A"){
  x[is.na(x)==T]  <- replacement

}

sapply(df,replace_NA,replacement ="N/A" )
```

Comment: You can just use `is.na(x)` and don't need to test with `==`. Also, it's generally encouraged to write out `TRUE`, since it is common to name a user-defined variable `T`. Finally, the typical practice is `df[] <- lapply(...)` rather than `sapply` since the latter tries to give you a matrix (when you probably still want a data.frame).

Comment: I thought `is.na(x)==TRUE`  would be more comprehend able to a new user

Comment: As I remarked to the first comment, there are no NA's in the data frame, just blanks for the missing data.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to reinvent the fixed-width file format. Your requested format would have a blank column between every real column. I don't find a `write.fwf`, although the 'utils' package has `read.fwf`. The simplest method of getting your requested output would be:

```
 capture.output(dat, file='test.dat')
# Result in a text file

  Sample Gene  RS Chromosome
1      1    A rs1         10
2      2    B              X
3      3    C rs4          Y
```

This essentially uses the `print` method (at the end of the R REPL) for dataframes to do the spacing for you.